# Android - Setting the width of a child to be fill_parent in GridLayout is resulting in the child being clipped

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, grid-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create a grid layout that works on both landscape and portrait on a tablet. I only have 2 columns but i'm running into a problem setting the width for the child.

Is set the `GridLayout` to `match_parent`. I then try to set my `TextView` inside the `GridLayout` to `match_parent`, thinking that it would stretch to fit inside the `GridLayout`. But I see that the `TextView`'s width is over the edge of the screen. (See Screenshot)

[image: Problem with GridLayout clipping]

If I delete the `TextView` in Column 0, it will stretch properly.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView17" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="7"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_rowSpan="21"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/phonebtn"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@drawable/phonebtn_cchange"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView127"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView128"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />
</GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I assume that i'm setting a weight wrong, or a col span but i'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can fit the child TextView by setting its width as 0dp and its layout gravity params as "fill". So GridLayout will know, that the width of the TextView is whatever the column width.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thank you!